# unhandled exception type filenotfoundexception, compilation problem

Tags: java, file-io, java-io, fileinputstream

I am trying to read file from disk however I am facing compilation error
on

```
 catch (Docx4JException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error("Błąd Docx4J: ", e);
                throw e;
            }
```

**unhandled exception type filenotfoundexception** Any ideas?

```
Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get(genConfig.getDocxJiraReportDirectory()));

        files.forEach(file -> {

            final WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage;

            try {
                wordMLPackage = fileGenerator.loadFile(genConfig.getDocxTemplateDirectory(),
                        params.getTemplateFileName());

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.toString());
                    String data = IOUtils.toString(fis, "UTF-8");

                    System.out.println(data);

                    String dataFinal = XmlHelper.GenerateEanImage(data);

                    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, dataFinal, Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);

                    String filePath = genConfig.getDocxReportDirectory() + "/" + file.getFileName();
                    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(filePath), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
            } catch (Docx4JException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error("Błąd Docx4J: ", e);
                throw e;
            }

        });
```

Comment: The issue is being spelled out. You have an unhandled (not caught) FileNotFoundException. Add a FileNotFoundException to your catch block.

Comment: But FileNotFoundException is a subclass of IOException

Comment: Perhaps because your first line where you get your Stream of files is not within your try/catch

Comment: ther errror is quite simple your catch en rethrox exception that is not a runtime exception : "throw e;" should be replace by "throw new RuntimeException(e);" this will fiw your compilation issue : consumer (used by the foreach) can't throw non runtime exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to re-throw the exception, wrap it inside RuntimeException.

```
    } catch (Docx4JException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Błąd Docx4J: {}", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Btw, you are missing a `{}` in `log.error`

Comment: `UncheckedIOException` would be better in this case, but it requires a little more complex `throw` clause.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov not for `Docx4JException`.

Comment: @Holger, yes, but I assume `Docx4JException` is unchecked, so you can do `throw (e instanceof Docx4JException) ? (RuntimeException) e : new UncheckedIOException(e);`. It's exactly what I meant by "more complex `throw` clause".

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it seems to be a checked exception, but anyway, if you want to treat them differently, it would be simpler to use two `catch` clauses for the two exception types.

Comment: @Holger, yes, you're right, it's also checked, so instead of a cast there'd be another wrapping. I slightly disagree about second try-catch, as everything that's before retrow will then have to be repeated twice, and it's not dry enough for my taste. Though I would say that this little detail is unlikely worth the brainpower we're giving it right now.